# Replicate the default list search box in a data view

Tags: 2013, list, search, data-view-web-part

I created a data view for a list so I can easily format the data but would really like to use the OOB list search box.  Is there a way to get this functionality on a data view?  I've tried using an HTML form web part but that doesn't 'search' it only matches the literal string.  I could also put a search box and search results web parts on the page and do it through that, but would really prefer to implement this in one web part so you use the same list to navigate in and search in.

Comment: if you're using 2013, you should think about JSLink instead of data-view. This would still allow the search to work

Comment: True, I'm formatting each item in a table which are inline with each other. I haven't dealt with as much JS Link and don't know if you would be able to format the data the same way or not.  I surely couldn't do it right now with the knowledge I have of JS Link.